# creating a record using rails 3.2.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
irb(main):016:0> subject  = Subject.new
=> #<Subject id: nil, name: nil, position: nil, visible: false, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):017:0> 
irb(main):017:0> subject = Subject.new(:name => "First", :position => 1, :value => true)
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: name, position, value
```

While creating a new record using rails 3.2.11 i got error as above. I can't understand wats the error is, how this record can be inserted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `Subject` model just add the line:

```
attr_accessible :name, :position, :value
```

Mass assignment security provides an interface for protecting attributes from end-user assignment. It specifies a white list of model attributes that can be set via mass-assignment, such as new(attributes), update_attributes(attributes), or attributes=(attributes).

More information:

- [ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html) - api.rubyonrails.org
- [attr_accessible](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attr_accessible/class) - apidoc.com

Answer (score 0):

They made a recent security change in `rails 3.2.3` that requires you to allow mass assignment explicitly by setting `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes` to `false`
http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/Rails-3-2-3-makes-mass-assignment-change-1498547.html

alternatively, instead of allowing mass assingment, you can just set the `attr_accessible` for the attributes in your model that you want to be able to change, e.g.

```
attr_accessible :name, :position, :value #....
```

Comment: Thank u so much this was the exact error that i have been faced, this occurred due to the some security reasons.